# neovim: how to select last entry on menu opening in nvim-cmp?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin, nvim.cmp

How can I get `cmp.complete()` in `nvim-cmp` to start from the last entry. This is default behavior in vim. I want `nvim-cmp` to open on pressing `<C-p>` and start from the end of completion list, if its open then select previous entry. `<C-n>` works similarly, it was easy to get that working. I want it to match the behavior that vim's default completion has. I use `select_prev_item()` twice for now to go to last entry. Thats hacky and slow. I tried this too, but here I want `cmp.complete()` to select last entry on open:

```lua
["<C-p>"] = function()
    if cmp.visible() then
        cmp.select_prev_item({ behavior = cmp.SelectBehavior.Insert })
    else
        cmp.complete({
            config = {
                reason = cmp.ContextReason.Auto,
                view = { entries = { selection_order = "bottom_up" }
                }
            }
        })
    end
end,
```